# Slowing Down a AC Centrifugal Fan

Tags: ac, fan, speed

I'm working with this blower, https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ebm-papst/D2E097-BE11-77?qs=DB9cKZ5ZWfV%252B%252BcGyCSU1bQ%3D%3D.

Is there an simple way of slowing down the speed without any adverse effects on the life of the motor?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the speed with a light dimmer, it's still 60Hz AC so no electrical change. Reducing speed will increase life because of reduced mechanical movement.

Comment: Good call! It's basically just a duty cycle control, correct?

Comment: You are correct.